# How to search multiple words in a single field using multi match in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How do I search multiple words in single field. Like I want to search "nokia charger"
Field 'prod_name' has = "Nokia 6300 Silver On Orange PAYG Mobile charger"

below is my code

```
"query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                             "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name","prod_model","keywords","prod_seo_keywords","prod_sku"],
                              "type" => "phrase",
                             "query" => "nokia charger"

                          ]
                     ],

                  ]
               ]
            ],

            ],
```

Right now I am trying below code and it is partially working, I want to add term.

```
 "query" => [

                          "multi_match" => [
                             "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name","prod_model","keywords","prod_seo_keywords","prod_sku"],
                              "type" => "phrase",
                             "query" => $query,

                              //"operator"=>   "and"
                          ],

            ],

            ],
       ];
      if (isset($prod_cat_type)) {
            $params['body']['query'][] = [
            'term' => ['productCategory' => $prod_cat_type],
            ];
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: share your code which you have tried

Comment: @DeepKakkar code updated